# Problems with finding efficient way of getting folder/file names/paths from drives

Tags: c#, treeview

I've been trying to learn how to create a Windows Explorer clone by using TreeView to hold all of the folder and file names and paths.

I looked up a lot of examples and they all used recursion which is fine, however, I've been trying to get a huge amount of folder/file names/paths (300k+) and it becomes quite slow (takes a few minutes to get all the data and put it into the TreeView).

Below is the recursion method I am using to get folder and file names and paths:

```
public static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, TreeNode parentNode = null)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            parentNode = new TreeNode(directory.Name);
            parentNode.Tag = directory.FullName;

            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory, parentNode));
        }

        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            TreeNode tnFile = new TreeNode(file.Name);
            tnFile.Tag = file.FullName;

            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(tnFile);
        }
        return directoryNode;
    }
```

Comment: Well - why don't you leave the tree un-expanded by default and only get files/folders for nodes in the tree that are actually visible?

Comment: @BrokenGlass I can't believe that I didn't think of something so simple...I suppose I tried to over think this waaay too much. That's a very good idea, thank you! This way I can just populate the first layer on a doubleclick event from each folder instead of everything